# Auth0 lock - failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, auth0

I'm trying to integrate Auth0 into React like it is shown [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login).

This is how my `Auth` class looks like:

```
class Auth {

  constructor() {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;
    this.lock0 = new Auth0Lock(clientID, domain, {
      container: 'login-container',
      theme: {
        primaryColor: '#FFC107',
      },
      languageDictionary: {
        emailInputPlaceholder: 'your_email@here.com',
        title: 'Authorize',
      },
      auth: {
        audience,
        redirectUrl: redirectUri,
        responseType,
        params: { scope },
      },
    });
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain,
      clientID,
      redirectUri,
      audience,
      responseType,
      scope,
    });
    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this);
    console.log('Auth class initialized');
  }

  show() {
    this.lock0.show();
  }

  login() {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }

  logout(history) {
    // Clear Access Token and ID Token from local storage
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
    // navigate to the home route
    history.replace(HOME_ROUTE);
  }

  handleAuthentication(history) {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      console.log('#handleAuthentication', { err, authResult });
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult, history);
        history.replace(HOME_ROUTE);
      } else if (err) {
        history.replace(HOME_ROUTE);
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  }

  setSession(authResult, history) {
    // Set the time that the Access Token will expire at
    const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
    // navigate to the home route
    history.replace(HOME_ROUTE);
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    // Check whether the current time is past the
    // Access Token's expiry time
    const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
    return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }
}

const auth = new Auth();
export default auth;
```

What I'm getting in the console is like 20 errors looking like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

As soon as I comment out the `this.lock0 = Auth0Lock...` part - they are gone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does this error happen when you signup/login with a user? or just when you load the page? what version of Lock are you using? Do you have any rules or database action scripts in Auth0? (if so we can add `console.logs` to to see the errors are being generated from there)

Comment: It happens when I load any page of my app as this app is instantiated on my app launch. I'm posting an edit with further info what I managed to do.

Comment: I'm going to leave this questions. It was caused by not having `http://localhost:3000` in allowed origins in my Auth0 app settings. It took a 10-15 minutes for the changes to apply.

Comment: okay great, glad you found the cause - feel free to send another message here if you have any further issues with integrating Auth0 into your react app.

Comment: Thanks @kimcodes!